# How to reduce the fetching time in view table?

Tags: sql

I have tried to fetch the data from view table .I have executed select query in phpmyadmin .It takes  5.2875 seconds. But normal table takes only 0.0300 seconds.
Query :

```
SELECT line FROM `summary_view` WHERE date='2022-02-25'
```

CREATE VIEW `summary_view` AS
select
`adh`.`id` AS `id`,
`adh`.`line` AS `line`,
`fam`.`area` AS `area`,
`fam`.`sub_area` AS `sub_area`,
`fam`.`family` AS `family`,
`pro`.`produced` AS `produced`,
`pro`.`service` AS `service`,
round(((`testdb`.`down` * 60) / `adh`.`takt_time`),0) AS `units_lost`,
round(((((`adh`.`worked_time` * 60) - `adh`.`break_time`) * 60) / `adh`.`takt_time`),0) AS `oa_capacity`,
round(((((`adh`.`plan_time` * 60) - `adh`.`break_time`) * 60) / `adh`.`takt_time`),0) AS `ay_capacity`,
`testdb`.`machines` AS `machines`,
`testdb`.`manpower` AS `manpower`,
`testdb`.`material` AS `material`,
`testdb`.`methods` AS `methods`,
`testdb`.`misc` AS `misc`,
`testdb`.`down` AS `down`,
round((((`pro`.`produced` + `pro`.`service`) * `adh`.`takt_time`) / 60),0) AS `uptime`,
`adh`.`break_time` AS `break_time`,
round(((`adh`.`worked_time` * 60) - (((((`pro`.`produced` + `pro`.`service`) * `adh`.`takt_time`) / 60) + `testdb`.`down`) + `adh`.`break_time`)),0) AS `minute_error`,
round((`adh`.`worked_time` * 60),0) AS `working_time`,
round(((`adh`.`worked_time` * 60) - `adh`.`break_time`),0) AS `worked_time`,
round(((`adh`.`plan_time` * 60) - `adh`.`break_time`),0) AS `plan_time`,
round(`adh`.`takt_time`,0) AS `takt_time`,
NULL AS `headcount`,
`rep`.`nff` AS `nff`,
`rep`.`dpu` AS `dpu`,
round(((((`pro`.`produced` + `pro`.`service`) * `adh`.`takt_time`) / 60) / ((`adh`.`worked_time` * 60) - `adh`.`break_time`)),4) AS `oa`,
round(((((`pro`.`produced` + `pro`.`service`) * `adh`.`takt_time`) / 60) / ((`adh`.`plan_time` * 60) - `adh`.`break_time`)),4) AS `ay`,
`adh`.`shift` AS `shift`,
`GET_MONTH`(`adh`.`date`) AS `month`,
`GET_WEEK`(`adh`.`date`) AS `week`,
`adh`.`date` AS `date`,
`adh`.`skey` AS `skey`
from
(
(
(
(
`adhoc` `adh`
left join
(
select
sum(if((`down`.`category` = 'Machines'),`down`.`duration`,NULL)) AS `machines`,
sum(if((`down`.`category` = 'Manpower'),`down`.`duration`,NULL)) AS `manpower`,
sum(if((`down`.`category` = 'Material'),`down`.`duration`,NULL)) AS `material`,
sum(if((`down`.`category` = 'Methods'),`down`.`duration`,NULL)) AS `methods`,
sum(if((`down`.`category` = 'Misc'),`down`.`duration`,NULL)) AS `misc`,
sum(`down`.`duration`) AS `down`,
`down`.`skey` AS `skey`
from (`down` join `family` on((`down`.`line` = `family`.`line`)))
where ((`down`.`reason` <> 'Scheduled Shutdown') and (`family`.`area` in ('Indoor','Outdoor','Specialty')))
group by `down`.`skey`
)
`testdb` on((`adh`.`skey` = `testdb`.`skey`))
)
left join
(
select
count(if((`prod`.`repair_flag` <> 'S'),1,NULL)) AS `produced`,
count(if((`prod`.`repair_flag` = 'S'),1,NULL)) AS `service`,
`prod`.`skey` AS `skey`
from (`prod` join `family` on((`prod`.`line` = `family`.`line`)))
group by `prod`.`skey`
)
`pro` on((`adh`.`skey` = `pro`.`skey`))
)
left join
(
select
count(if((`repair`.`level_one` = 'No Fault Found'),1,NULL)) AS `nff`,
count(if(((`repair`.`level_one` <> 'No Fault Found') and (`repair`.`level_two` <> 'Reclaim Refrigerant')),1,NULL)) AS `dpu`,
`repair`.`skey` AS `skey`
from `repair`
group by `repair`.`skey`
)
`rep` on((`adh`.`skey` = `rep`.`skey`))
)
join `family` `fam` on((`adh`.`line` = `fam`.`line`))
)
where (`adh`.`area` = 'Assembly')
;

How to reduce the query execution time in view table ?
Is there any way to reduce the execution time without adding index ?

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the view definition and on the presence of indexes in the underlying tables. Please include the view definition. Remember that views are just syntactic sugar for your queries; they don't hold data.

Comment: First of all, does the table `adh` have an index on tha column `date`? It could help the query.

Comment: Also, `down` should have an index on (`skey`, `line`); `prod` shoud have the same index. `repair` should have an index on `skey`; `family` should have an index on `line`.

Comment: Is there any way without adding index ?